# Is there any way to get the class name of an old style (Borland Pascal) object instance in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I have a lot of descendant of my class:

```
PMyAncestor =^TMyAncestor;
TMyAncestor = object
  public
    constructor init;
    destructor done; virtual;
    // There are virtual methods as well
end;

PMyDescendant1 =^TMyDescendant1;
TMyDescendant1 = object ( TMyAncestor )
end;

PMyDescendant2 =^TMyDescendant2;
TMyDescendant2 = object ( TMyAncestor )
end;

PMyDescendant3 =^TMyDescendant3;
TMyDescendant3 = object ( TMyDescendant2 )
end;

procedure foo;
var
  pMA1, pMA2, pMA3, pMA4 : PMyAncestor;
  s : string;
begin
  pMA1 := new( PMyAncestor, init );
  pMA2 := new( PMyDescendant1, init );
  pMA3 := new( PMyDescendant2, init );
  pMA4 := new( PMyDescendant3, init );
  try
    s := some_magic( pMA1 ); // s := "TMyAncestor"
    s := some_magic( pMA2 ); // s := "TMyDescendant1"
    s := some_magic( pMA3 ); // s := "TMyDescendant2"
    s := some_magic( pMA4 ); // s := "TMyDescendant3"
  finally
    dispose( pMA4, done );
    dispose( pMA3, done );
    dispose( pMA2, done );
    dispose( pMA1, done );
  end;
end;
```

Is there any way to get the class name of its descendant instances? I don't want to create a virtual method for this reason (there are thousands of descendants).
I know there is the `typeOf(T)` operator. But what is its return type? OK. Pointer. But what can I cast it for? The cast to `PTypeInfo` seems to be wrong.

Comment: The current way to do this is 'ClassName', but I don't know if it was around in Delphi 7. I imagine not...

Comment: @Dsm The ClassName is a method of TObject descendants. Unfortunately my base class is the much more older Borland Pascal base type, not this one. (Created by the new, released by the dispose operators)

Comment: Surely it's time to move on and use a Delphi class

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is not possible. This is a giga legacy project. Don't you have any idea, David? Then it is surly the end of the story!

Comment: I think you also know that what you are trying to do is not possible either.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes. This was my idea. But I trusted that there would be some other way. It looks like I have to create that virtual method! :( Do you have any idea what should be the return type of `typeOf`?

Comment: The only way you can use `TypeOf` is to compare with a given type: `if TypeOf(pMA1^) = TypeOf(TMyAncestor) then ...`.

Comment: @LURD Yes. I know these usage way. But I tried to expand the boundary of the opportunities.

Comment: Well, you can still use it to find the correct object type name.

Comment: @LURD Your idea gives a wiered solution. What if I want to create a new type? I have to create a new if statement in the centralized code...

Comment: I'm not telling you that it is easy, only that it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I compile this code, and search for the names of your classes in the compiled executable, they are not found.

From this I conclude that what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: I was afraid of that, too :(

Comment: By comparing with `TypeOf` it is possible to get the correct name of the object type. See my comment to the question.

Comment: @LURD If you write a lookup table for the types in your program. then yes it is possible. I interpret the question as, "can the type name be found without including such a lookup table?"

Comment: In the question it is clear that  the use of `TypeOf` is not known. The OP asks for a magic function to reveal the object type. I would say that `TypeOf` is exactly that magic function, only that it returns a pointer that defines the type, not a string. Whether that requires use of a lookup table or not, is implementation detail, and we can't tell.

Comment: @LURD "Is there any way to get the class name?"

Comment: The result of `TypeOf` can be used the same way as an object name.

Comment: @LURD Not if you want to present text to a user. I mean, perhaps the asker wants text for a reason.  Or perhaps type identity is what matters, not the textual value.  But the question does ask for text.

Comment: I need the class name for logging. I looking for memory leaks. I log object creation, destruction and collect the unpaired ones.

Comment: Full debug FastMM would surely solve this problem. It beggars belief that you feel that you can change every single creation and destruction of objects, but you can't switch to classes!

Comment: I could not find any useful information in FastMM4 full debug logs. It should be fine, but I don't know it enough. I just put 1-1 log call in the upmost ascendant object type constructor/destructor. Rerun the program I can trace the right constructor call by this details.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to catch the old style object type names.

Using `TypeOf()`, it is possible to test if the object is equal to a type:

```
if TypeOf(pMA1^) = TypeOf(TMyAncestor) then ...
```

It can also be used to build a lookup-table, in order to match with the actual type name.
This can be a bit tedious if there are many object types to record in such a table.

---

In a comment, it is said it would be used to catch memory leaks by logging the names during the base object initialization/finalization.

Here is an example that does the logging, but instead of the type names, loggs the type names addresses. It also prints the base object name and address, which can be useful to pinpoint leaks. The object addresses are numbered in order of declaration, and it should be fairly straight forward to identify the leaking object with that knowledge.

```
program Project121;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

Type
  PMyAncestor =^TMyAncestor;
  TMyAncestor = object
   public
    constructor init;
    destructor done; virtual;
    // There are virtual methods as well
  end;

  PMyDescendant1 =^TMyDescendant1;
  TMyDescendant1 = object ( TMyAncestor )
  end;

  PMyDescendant2 =^TMyDescendant2;
  TMyDescendant2 = object ( TMyAncestor )
  end;

  PMyDescendant3 =^TMyDescendant3;
  TMyDescendant3 = object ( TMyDescendant2 )
  end;

constructor TMyAncestor.init;
begin
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  WriteLn( IntToHex(Integer(TypeOf(Self))),
           ' Base class - TMyAncestor:',
           IntToHex(Integer(TypeOf(TMyAncestor))));
{$ENDIF}
end;

destructor TMyAncestor.done;
begin
{$IFDEF DEBUG}
  WriteLn(IntToHex(Integer(TypeOf(Self))),' Done.');
{$ENDIF}
end;

procedure foo;
var
  pMA1, pMA2, pMA3, pMA4 : PMyAncestor;
  s : string;
begin
  pMA1 := new( PMyAncestor, init );
  pMA2 := new( PMyDescendant1, init );
  pMA3 := new( PMyDescendant2, init );
  pMA4 := new( PMyDescendant3, init );
  try
    (*
      Do something
    *)
  finally
    dispose( pMA4, done );
    dispose( pMA3, done );
    dispose( pMA2, done );
    dispose( pMA1, done );
  end;
end;

begin
  foo;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Outputs:

```
0041AD98 Base class - TMyAncestor:0041AD98
0041ADA8 Base class - TMyAncestor:0041AD98
0041ADB8 Base class - TMyAncestor:0041AD98
0041ADC8 Base class - TMyAncestor:0041AD98
0041ADC8 Done.
0041ADB8 Done.
0041ADA8 Done.
0041AD98 Done.
```

Comment: The type pointer is useless for me. I log the instance pointer yet. Plus a log entry counter (create/destroy separately) to make it catchable when I rerun the "test case". The class name needed to make logs more readable human tracing. I have created the disliked virtual method and override it in the most important types. The others writes the default value : `Object`. I will override the ones get important in the future. But I want to avoid it if would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Delphi documentation has to say about Object types

> The Delphi compiler allows an alternative syntax to class types. You
>   can declare object types using the syntax:

```
type objectTypeName = object (ancestorObjectType)
         memberList
      end;
```

> where objectTypeName is any valid identifier, (ancestorObjectType) is
>   optional, and memberList declares fields, methods, and properties. If
>   (ancestorObjectType) is omitted, then the new type has no ancestor.
>   Object types cannot have published members.
>
> Since object types do not descend from System.TObject, they provide no
>   built-in constructors, destructors, or other methods. You can create
>   instances of an object type using the New procedure and destroy them
>   with the Dispose procedure, or you can simply declare variables of an
>   object type, just as you would with records.
>
> Object types are supported for backward compatibility only. Their use
>   is not recommended.

So the answer to your question is NO.

Object types that you use do not contain necessary methods for retrieving class name as normal classes that descends from TObject do have.

What can you do now?

You can modify your existing object so that you add additional data field in which you will store their name and then read this name when you need it. You will have to set this value at object creation by yourself.

Or you could go and replace all of your objects with true classes that descend from TObject so that you automatically gat all class functionality. This generally more recommended approach even thou Object types might have a few advantages over classes in certain scenarios.

Comment: This is a nice explanation of the prehistoric object type but not an answer to the question. The solution you recommend is part of the question. Not a new idea. It expect a getName method. It is the same to create virtual methods for every descendant or mofify their contructors one by one.

Comment: @User007 As far as I can see the answer does answer your question. "So the answer to your question is NO."